# OpenLayers5: hitTolerance doesn't seem to work with WMS layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

I am new to OpenLayers as I just today tried porting over my map from Leaflet to OL since `hitTolerance` is exactly what I was looking for. Also, I understand v5 is quite new, so the docs are not completely updated in my experience.

I can't seem to get `hitTolerance` to work with WMS layers.

I understand that since v5 you can now specify `hitTolerance` in `forEachLayerAtPixel`, but I still have to hit the layer pretty accurately for it to be picked up by `forEachLayerAtPixel`.

I also tried `forEachFeatureAtPixel`, but that gave me nothing, ever. Does WMS layers have features?

I have tried both with `TileLayer/TileWMS` and `ImageLayer/ImageWMS`. Both behave the same. Using `forEachLayerAtPixel` even with a `hitTolerance` of `100` I still have to be very precise to hit the layer.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't know if this is a bug, or if `hitTolerance` simply doesn't work with WMS layers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hitTolerance` applies to vector data. OL takes your click coordinates and searches for nearby features.

When dealing with WMS, OL has no knowledge of the features, it is just displaying an image. It just sends the click coordinates to the map server, which may or not apply a buffer to it, and return the found features info.

So, for WMS, the hit tolerance is a server setting, not a client one.

For example, here is the corresponding [doc](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#buffer) for Geoserver.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was afraid of. Unfortunately the data source I am using only supports wms, but I will ask them if they support the buffer parameter. Thanks.